# jQuery Form Validation Plugin's issue with only literal field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, validation

I've got this issue: i created an additional rule that checks if a field match a regular expression.
Everything works flawless with every other fields but when i validate one that has maxlength = 1, it just doesn't work.

Here is the HTML

```
 <section class="col col-1">
      <label class="label" for="field">FIELD</label>
      <input id="field" name="field" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1">
 </section>
```

And here is the Javascript code

```
 $('#form').validate({
      rules: {
           field:
           {
                required: true,
                accept: '[a-zA-Z]+',
                maxlength: 1
           },
      },
      messages: {
           field:
           {
                required: 'blablabla',
                accept: 'bububu',
                maxlength: 'not 1'
           }
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the pattern rule from additional-methods.js, the [accept-method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/) is for testing the mime file for file fields.

```
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            pattern: /^[a-z]$/i,
            maxlength: 1
        },
    },
    messages: {
        field: {
            required: 'blablabla',
            accept: 'bububu',
            maxlength: 'not 1'
        }
    }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/asuhro1o/)

Comment: Thanks man! Although i changed my 'accept' method with another name it didn't worked. The pattern solution works!